# jqueryui - How to add to sortable which is using float: left?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a 2-column container of a bunch of left-floating elements. I want to be able to add arbitrarily many new elements to it by *dragging* clones of another element to inside the sortable.

The issue I'm having is that when I *drag* the new box up to the sortable boxes, I get a lot of **flickering** and it's very difficult to get the box into the correct location. What am I doing wrong?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ugV3R/3/)'s an example demonstrating the issue

HTML:

```
<div id='box_container'>
    <div class='box' style='background: red;'></div>
    <div class='box' style='background: green;'></div>
    <div class='box' style='background: blue;'></div>
    <div style='clear: both;'></div>
</div>

<div id='new_box_container'>
    <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#box_container').sortable();
$('#new_box_container .box').draggable({
    items: '.box',
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: '#box_container',
    connectToSortable: '#box_container'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with the `connectWith` option of a second `sortable` rather than `draggable`. jQuery seems to behave better with it:

```
$('#box_container').sortable();

$('#new_box_container').sortable({
    connectWith:'#box_container'
})
```

Note that I didn't give the first `sortable` a `connectWith` so it only lets you drag one way. I believe that was your intention.

You'll also need to redo the clone aspect of it, but this isn't giving me any flickers.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xu5vG/